# Integrate Radio DNS in .net site

Tags: .net, integration, internet-radio

I need to Integrate Radio DNS in .net site. Here are the link on the library.
 http://radiodns.org/developers/libraries/

But  i read the document there no any way to integrate this with .net.

Can any one puss me in right direction..

Thanks

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: i am not able to find the library that will integrate with .net

Comment: 1) You should mention this in the question otherwise it's unclear 2)If you mention it in the question it will be closed as off-topic. You should read SO rules before asking the questions. I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a .NET API for RadioDNS, but as it's an open collaborative project you would of course be encouraged to help develop and contribute one.

The technical specification includes the detail you would need to attempt this process and the libraries in other languages should provide good inspiration to tackle porting.

Comment: can you please suggest me the other reference library that can integrate with .net

Comment: Libraries for other languages can be found on the official website: http://radiodns.org/developers/libraries/